# How do I handle window resizing in SlimDX?

Tags: c#, directx9, slimdx, windows-forms

I'm considering the use of SlimDX in a managed Windows Forms Application. Available with DirectX is DXUT. I use DXUT to handle events such as window resizing and 'lost devices.'

How well does SlimDX account for these occurrences? If I were to use SlimDX, how would I account for the functionality of DXUT in managed code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SlimDX is a lightweight wrapper around DirectX APIs, and DXUT isn't a core DirectX API. Thus, SlimDX doesn't wrap it.

If you want to deal with window management, resizing, et cetera, you have to do that yourself using the [Windows Forms API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984427%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). When your form handles a resize event, you may need to deal with resizing your back buffer or viewport, depending on your specific needs.

Note that "lost device" scenarios are *not* something core to DXUT, they are an aspect of Direct3D 9 and are perfectly supported by SlimDX in basically exactly the same way you'd handle them natively.

Comment: What about the callbacks used in DXUT when the device is lost? How does SlimDX notify the application? Can I set callbacks for these scenarios? How would I release( or Dispose() ) the resources held in video memory?

Comment: SlimDX notifies your application the same way D3D9 does: the return code of [Present](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174423(v=vs.85).aspx) or [TestCooperativeLevel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174472(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: thanks! i found some deprecated samples [here](http://code.google.com/p/slimdx/downloads/detail?name=SlimDX%20Samples%20%28Nov%2007%29.zip&can=4&q=) . These samples are more substantial than the current ones found on website...